# Google Chrome error

Tags: google-chrome

I have installed Google Chrome by *.deb* file from *google.com/chrome/* 
Installation was ok but when I opening through terminal it says the code below although it opens it self. And it's unopenable from launcher.

Help me please

```
drinkon@drinkon:~$ google-chrome
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[6662:6662:0918/163724:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(308)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process
[6622:6622:0918/163724:ERROR:desktop_window_tree_host_x11.cc(1478)] Not implemented reached in void views::DesktopWindowTreeHostX11::MapWindow(ui::WindowShowState)
```

EDIT:
Not it gives me this:

```
google-chrome
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[2647:2647:0922/182234:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(308)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process
[2607:2607:0922/182238:ERROR:desktop_window_tree_host_x11.cc(1478)] Not implemented reached in void views::DesktopWindowTreeHostX11::MapWindow(ui::WindowShowState)
[2607:2607:0922/182315:ERROR:CONSOLE(26)] "Uncaught Error: Assertion failed", source: chrome://resources/js/util.js (26)
[2607:2818:0922/182317:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(240)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
[2607:2644:0922/183114:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(335)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -21
[2607:2644:0922/183143:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(335)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
[2607:2644:0922/183324:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(335)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -21
[2607:2644:0922/183348:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(335)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
[2607:2644:0922/183438:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(335)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
[2607:2644:0922/183617:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(335)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
[2607:2644:0922/183945:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(335)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
[2607:2644:0922/184631:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(335)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
[2607:2644:0922/185631:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(335)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -106
[2607:2818:0922/185842:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(240)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
[2607:2818:0922/185843:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(240)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
[2607:2818:0922/185845:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(240)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
[2607:2818:0922/185848:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(240)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
[2607:2818:0922/185855:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(240)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
[2607:2818:0922/185906:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(240)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
[2607:2818:0922/185908:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(240)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
[WARNING:flash/platform/pepper/pep_module.cpp(63)] SANDBOXED
```

Comment: could you please post the result of the following command: `dpkg -l libxcursor1`

Comment: Thank your concern. It says this: dpkg -l libxcursor1
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  libxcursor1:i3 1:1.1.14-1   i386         X cursor management library

Comment: ok, this was because there is a bug with libxcursor 1.1.14-2 that causes chrome to crash in the way you describe, but apperently your version is not problematic, so I'm sorry I'm not able to help more...

Comment: Hello, now it gives me another response. I've edited first post..

Comment: You should file a bug report to google chrome's team: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en    and you could also try google chrome beta to see if the issue already has been fixed: https://www.google.es/chrome/browser/beta.html

Comment: And this may be helpful http://superuser.com/questions/763204/trouble-with-google-chrome-on-ubuntu

Comment: There is a solution to this, I recal it from a while back... you need to set something up in the shadow file is all I remember. I'll look for that info

Comment: after first attempt failed you should check in directory for Downloads if *.deb - file is written in red (then it is malformed or touched) + the next attempt to download and install should then run better than the first attempt + in case it still fails you can see this in terminal when doing there the usual : sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable + there then will be the output which package is missing as dependency to be resolved.

Answer (score 7):

This is a bug related with GPU rendering options, but not all bugs are problematics.

If you don't want to see those messages, open your browser adding extra option in command line.

```
google-chrome --disable-gpu
```

or

```
google-chrome > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This bug is reported since [chrome/chromium 33 in 2013](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=319267).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar problems when I installed Chrome. It may be related to the way in which the computer connects to the DNS Server because I'd get this error when I was connecting to the work network but not when I was connecting to my home wifi.

I ended up uninstalling Google Chrome and installed Chromium Browser instead. Not only is the installation easier, but it's less resource intensive and works exactly like Chrome for all intents and purposes (all your Chrome bookmarks sync seamlessly into Chromium and the interface is pretty much identical).

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

Try using chromium. It's into he Ubuntu App Store. It's the open source version of chrome. Just search chrome in the search bar or App Store.